# How can I identify pairs of identical values in an Excel column named ‘Current’ and return the corresponding values from the ‘No. Feeders’ column?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2007

| No. Feeders | No of WTG | WTG Power (MW) | Current |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F4 | 11 | 2.3 MW | 470.43 A |
| F5 | 6 | 2.3 MW | 256.6 A |
| F6 | 6 | 2.3 MW | 256.6 A |
| F7 | 11 | 2.3 MW | 470.43 A |
| F8 | 3 | 2.3 MW | 128.3 A |
| F9 | 7 | 2.3 MW | 299.37 A |
| F10 | 6 | 2.3 MW | 256.6 A |
| F11 | 11 | 2.3 MW | 470.43 A |
| F12 | 3 | 2.3 MW | 128.3 A |

End result I want is to Concat this pairs and associate its current value

1. F4, F7, F11 with current value 470.43 A
2. F5, F6, F10 with current value 256.6 A
3. F8, F12 with current value 128.3 A
4. F9 with current value 299.37 A

The formula should be dynamic such that when No. Feeders and No of WTG changes we get new pairs with corresponding current values.

VBA is fine too.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to do this by formula in an early version of Excel where there is no textjoin, you would need a helper column in column E say pulled down as necessary to get the concatenation:

```
=IF(A2="","",IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(D$1:D1=D2),E$1:E1)&","&A2,A2))
```

Then a standard formula to get the unique values of current in say column G:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D$2:D$100,MATCH(0,IF(D$2:D$100="",1,COUNTIF(G1:G$1,D$2:D$100)),0)),"")
```

And finally a lookup in column H to get the last matching value from column E:

```
=IF(G2="","",LOOKUP(2,1/(G2=D$2:D$100),E$2:E$100))
```

[image]

It is dynamic in the limited sense that the ranges can be made as big as necessary to include any future data.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Tom! That worked like magic!
Additionally, is there a way to get feeder pairs in H2 cell like
F1,F2,F3,F4,F7 we rewrite it as F1 to F4, F7 dynamically. Thanks.

Comment: The answer is 'maybe'. It's quite a big ask in Excel 2007, but in this particular case where the Feeders are identified by an 'F' followed by a number which is always increasing, I think you could.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: VBA

`Dictionary` object is used to group by the data.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData, arrRes, sKey, arrKey
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rngData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 2) & "|" & arrData(i, 3) & "|" & arrData(i, 4)
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            objDic(sKey) = objDic(sKey) & "," & arrData(i, 1)
        Else
            objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim arrRes(objDic.Count, 1 To UBound(arrData, 2))
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
        arrRes(0, i) = arrData(1, i)
    Next
    j = 1
    For Each sKey In objDic
        arrKey = Split(sKey, "|")
        For i = 0 To 2
            arrRes(j, i + 2) = arrKey(i)
        Next
        arrRes(j, 1) = objDic(sKey)
        j = j + 1
    Next sKey
    Sheets.Add
    Range("A1").Resize(j, UBound(arrData, 2)) = arrRes
    Set objDic = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

---

Option 2: Power Query

Update table name (Table1) as needed.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"No. Feeders", type text}, {"No of WTG", type text}, {"WTG Power (MW)", type text}, {"Current", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"No of WTG", "WTG Power (MW)", "Current"}, {{"No. Feeders", each Text.Combine([No. Feeders], ","), type text}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"No. Feeders", "No of WTG", "WTG Power (MW)", "Current"})    
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

Comment: Thanks @taller-excelhome! I was amazed at how short the code for Power Query is!!

Comment: PQ is a really powerful built-in tool in Excel.